# Solve $2\sin(x)^2 -\sin(x) = 1$ by hand

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I'm am trying to solve

$ 2\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)=1 $

and I know that the solutions are:

$ x=\frac{1}{4}(4\pi~ n+\pi)$, 
$x=\pi(2n-\frac{1}{6})$, and $ x=\pi(2n+\frac{7}{6})$, (for any integer $n$).

But I have no idea where to start, any thoughts?

Thank's in advance

Comment: A start: $2\sin^2 x-\sin x-1=(2\sin x+1)(\sin x-1)$. The solutions given don't seem quite right.

Answer (score 2):

I'll be happy to give you a starting point.

Let $u = \sin{x}$.  Then our equation $2 \sin^{2}(x) - \sin{x} = 1$ becomes $2 u^{2} - u = 1$.  Then $2u^{2} - u - 1 = 0$, and factoring gives: $(2u + 1)(u - 1) = 0$.

The price for this starting point is now you must attempt the rest of the problem on your own and post your attempts before receiving any further help (at least from me).

Answer (score 0):

$$2\sin(x)^2 -\sin(x) = 1 \implies 2\sin(x)^2 -\sin(x) - 1=0 \implies \sin(x)=\frac{1\pm3}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\sin(x)$. Then, the equation $2y^2-y=1$, this is
$$2y^2-y-1=0,$$
has solutions $y_1=1$ and $y_2=-\frac{1}{2}$ (ok so far?). So you have:
$$\sin(x)=1\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi,\ k\in\Bbb Z$$
and
$$\sin(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=\frac{7}{6}\pi+2k\pi,\ k\in\Bbb Z\ \vee\ x=\frac{11}{6}\pi+2k\pi,\ k\in\Bbb Z.$$
If you like, for all $k\in\Bbb Z$, it is $\frac{11}{6}\pi+2k\pi=-\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi$.